# exp-00026 conflicting modes specified oracle

Tags: oracle, export, par, exp

I have below export command for exporting the schema which i want to run in command prompt. When i run this below commnd i am getting an error `exp-00026 conflicting modes specified oracle`.

```
exp RATOR_MONITORING/RATOR_MONITORING@10.127.666.777/O2P0RTE PARFILE=exp02_rm.par
```

The exp02_rm.par file has below information:

```
OWNER=RATOR_MONITORING
LOG=exp02_rm.log
FILE=exp02_rm.dmp
TABLES=KPI_LOGS,ALERT_LOGS
INDEXES=Y
CONSTRAINTS=Y
GRANTS=Y
COMPRESS=Y
FULL=N
ROWS=Y
CONSISTENT=Y
BUFFER=102035256
FEEDBACK=500
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the error is EXP-00026, which says

```
" only one parameter (TABLES, OWNER, or FULL) can be specified"
```

so you can't have both OWNER and TABLES specified as part of the export, one or the either but not both

Comment: Thanks very much.It works :). Just small question i have 30 tables so will it work if i tries for e.g TABLES = (table1,table2.......table30) ? And dont we have exclude option for EXP command. I know we have it in EXPDP.

Comment: yeah 30 tables is not many, there probably is an upper limit but it will be alot higher than 30. Could you mark this as the correct answer please. thanks.

Comment: i am sorry but i have an issue now.When i removed OWNER=RATOR_MONITORING from par file then it works but the only tables has been exportes. It does not export packages,views,sequences,triggers. Can you please tell me how to do that ?

Comment: don't think you are going to be able to do that with one export, try looking at this https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:743825617527 fo a possible solution. By the way my answer to your question was correct.

Comment: ok davegreen if its not possible to do in single export then its not feasible to exclude Owner but i will be having problem with the tables then.